# Build Drawing Cache

Tags: android, build, drawing, cache-control

I am working on a game application. But there is some problem to get background 
color base on build drawing cache with fix "X" and "Y" coordinate.

My code is like this..

```
mainRelativeLayout.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = mainRelativeLayout.getDrawingCache();
        int color = bitmap.getPixel(200,320);
        Log.e("color", "" + color);
```

but it return null pointer exception on color.

Comment: getDrawingCache() will return null in case you didn't enable it. Try calling this method before that: setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)

Answer (score 1):

I think this post will help you get a bitmap from the view, even if the content is out of screen.

[Call to `getDrawingCache` returns null when scroll is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560882/call-to-getdrawingcache-fails-on-api-8-everytime)